# IE Automation - Excel VBA ... Running Into Errors After Loading Website

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have programmed VBA to interact with IE rather extensively and have started to do so again, but am coming across a weird phenomenon that I cannot seem to solve with all the research I've done.

As soon as I load the website, I lose all reference to the `InternetExplorer Application` and can no longer work with the object.

When I check for the site being fully loaded, I got a `Run-Time Error 424 Object Required`, or a `Run-time error '-2147023179 (...)': Automation Error The interface is Unknown`

If I move past this line (while seeing the site fully loaded) and run the `Set doc ...` line, I get `Run-Time Error 462: The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable`.

I am using IE 11 and Excel 2010. I have VBAProject References to Microsoft Internet Controls and MicrosoftHTML Object Library, but the errors occur with late binding as well.

```
Sub LoginToFXAll()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

With ieApp

    .Visible = True

    .Navigate "https://www.google.com/" 

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE ''<- Run-Time Error 424 occurs here


    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = .Document '<- Run-Time Error 462 occurs here
    doc.all("q").Value = "Scott"

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I had a problem like it, does your network uses some kind of security? If so, the problem is that the IE instance while validate your "access rights" is "destroyed" and "rebuild", hence, the original object is lost

Comment: Thanks @Sgdva - I do have a feeling its security related, but can't "prove it" yet. Do you find anyway to work around it or to assign the new object? (I suspect not).

Comment: Sadly, I didn't at the time found a solution for it , but, now that I know a little more about it, probably you could get the memory location of the internet explorer instead of the element itself and somehow reference to it, sadly, I can't test it at the moment if it will work, but, that may be a good workaround, check my response for guidelines on how could be worked with [ObjPtr](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/199824)

Answer (score 0):

After the IE is created, probably you could get the memory allocation for it and luckily will be the same after the security network is done.

```
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef destination As Any, ByRef source As Any, ByVal length As Long)
#Else
    Public Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef destination As Any, ByRef source As Any, ByVal length As Long)
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
Function GetMemoryAddress(ByVal IEPointer As LongPtr) As Object
#Else
Function GetMemoryAddress(ByVal IEPointer As Long) As Object
#End If
        Dim objIE As Object
        CopyMemory objIE, GetMemoryAddress, LenB(GetMemoryAddress)
        Set GetMemoryAddress = objIE
        Set objIE = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Nice! I'm going to test it for me once I cross the sharepoint problem again -I didn't think about this possibility at the time-